# How to update kernel in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, updates

I have just downloaded 3 files to update my kernel. The files are as follows:

```
linux-image-4.9.22-040922-generic_4.9.22-040922.201704120731_i386.deb  
linux-headers-4.9.22-040922-generic_4.9.22-040922.201704120731_i386.deb  
linux-headers-4.9.22-040922_4.9.22-040922.201704120731_all.deb
```

And I installed them using Ubuntu store but my kernel version is the same what should I do to update it ?
For what is it worth my kernel version is 4.4.0-72-generic (at least that what shows when I type `uname -r` in the terminal)

Comment: When you installed with Ubuntu store, did it update your grub too ?

Comment: No I don't think so...but I updated it manually using sudo update-grub.

Comment: when booting can you see if there is an entry for your new kernel in grub menu ?

Comment: Hmmm I didn't try that let me check it@Greg.

Comment: @Greg thank you very much I have solved my problem thanks to you(though now I have a problem with my new kernel)

Comment: Why do you want to install 4.9.22 kernel?

Comment: My current version doesn't allow my laptop to shut down completely but version 4.9.22 makes it shutdown alright.
@jarno

Comment: Are you sure an earlier version could not do?

Comment: I'm not sure I tried this one and it worked but it is giving me other problems can you tell me where to find the latest stable kernel version ?  
@jarno

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 12):

Read [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus) how to upgrade kernel in Ubuntu 16.04. That way you will get security updates. Currently the kernel is 4.8.0-46-generic.

Comment: To boot to that by default, you might want to purge the 4.9.22 kernel, when booted by other kernel (you chose in grub menu).

Comment: Okay I'm installing the Kernel but my internet connection is slow I will post back when I'm done with the results.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help Kernel 4.9.0-46-generic is giving problems as well

Comment: I suppose you meant kernel 4.8.0-46. What kind of problems?

Comment: sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04   for 64 bit system it worked for me now i have Linux 4.10.0-38-generic