# Ubuntu 16.04 update kernel hangs at run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.9.35-040935-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic

Tags: 16.04, kernel, dpkg, dkms

I'm still a newbie when it comes to Ubuntu and I've run into some problems when trying to update the kernel.

I've followed instructions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905049/how-to-update-kernel-in-ubuntu-16-04) trying to update the kernel but it always gets stuck here:

```
Setting up linux-image-4.9.35-040935-generic (4.9.35-040935.201706290837) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.9.35-040935-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.9.35-040935-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.9.35-040935-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.9.35-040935-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic
```

And then it repeats the first error again. I've found [this page](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/) with some suggestions. Running `sudo apt-get update –fix-missing` gives me this at the end:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/floe/beignet/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/floe/beignet/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Running `sudo apt-get install -f` (and sometimes when trying to update or install something) gives me this:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
~$ sudo apt-get install -f
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
    ~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
        Setting up linux-image-4.9.35-040935-generic (4.9.35-040935.201706290837) ...
    Running depmod.
    update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
    The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.9.35-040935-generic
    vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic
    ) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic
     (/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.9.35-040935-generic.postinst line 491.
    Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.9.35-040935-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.9.35-040935-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.35-040935-generic
```

Which takes me back to the first error. I'm a bit nervous about [editing the dpkg status manually](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/) since it sounds like I could accidentally cause more problems.

If it makes any difference, I'm running Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and this is what I get when checking the current kernel version.

```
~$ uname -r
4.4.0-43-Microsoft
~$ uname -a
Linux LAPTOP-CMEAJ743 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```